# SQL help about selecting 3 rows in a specific order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a SQL query that will always return either 2 or 3 rows; when 3 are returned, got to sort them like this: team1, draw, team2

So basically if "draw" is in the list, then it should always be placed between the other two rows whatever they are, assuming the name of the teams and draw are in column "title"

I have tried ordering by `CASE WHEN title = 'draw' THEN 1`, also tried `FIELD()` - no luck :(

Could anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show how your table looks like and your best effort.

Comment: I think this is a symptom of a poor table structure.  Could you add the DDL of the table you are `SELECT`ing from? I think you need to normalize better, but we'd need to see the definitions for that.

Comment: It's should only require an `ORDER BY` with a `CASE` expression.  Revise your question and show the query you have so far and I'm sure it can be easily answered

Comment: Agree with BellevueBob, also show some of the sample data rows and what your expectation out of this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY (IF(title='team1', 1, IF(title='team2', 3, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Teams differ from results. I believe you should not solve your problem. Instead, create three tables: Teams, Results and ResultTypes. In ResultTypes store any possible result between two teams. In Teams, store the teams, their names and any relevant data to them. Finally, in Results store 3 Foreign keys. Two of them should reference to the Teams table and one to the ResultTypes table. This way you will never have problems with selecting data from your database.

Comment: That table is actually called "Bets" and for each event, we can have up to about 10000 of them. A bet can be placed for team1, draw, team2, then on a variety of other things such as correct score 1-0, number of goals and so on. The table has a field for id, another for title (of the bet), another for odds, among other things.